# unable to send email

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendmail

I'm getting an error message:

```
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

Command

```
date | mail -s "test" -r some@myemail.com some@myemail.com
```

mailutils install via this command

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

I have did the same in another ec2 server, and that server is working fine.
what could be the reason?

Debug info:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail exited with: 75
generic yields 38=Function not implemented
```

try to google this error message, but without any luck

Comment: there is no `-d` option

Answer (score 0):

I do not use the ec2 server, but had the same error message when trying to send an email, from the command line to my gmail account with ...

echo "hello" | mail -s "test email from CLI" myusername@gmail.com

My problem was finally solved, when I took out the special character in my gmail password. If using ssmtp, don't forget to update ssmtp.conf with the new password.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
export subject="Report -  $(date +'%d-%b-%Y')"  
echo "Hi All,  
            Please find the Report as an attachment.

 

Regards.....
Vittal manikonda.
" > message.txt


mail -e'set content_type=text/html' -a aggregateResults.html -s "Report -  $(date +'%d-%b-%Y')"  vittal.manikonda@xxx.com < message.txt
```